# C# Winform load method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing WinForm app where every new form is child form of main form. Every time I call menustripitem click I use such code:

```
bool opened = false;
foreach (Form forma in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (forma is frm_formname)
    {
        opened = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!opened)
{
    frm_formname frm = new frm_formname();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form already exist");
}
```

How can I change the code to make a method from this code where I will pass formname and mainformname as parameter and on click event call this method sending this 2 parameters not the whole code?

Comment: what is the constrain in moving the code to a separate function. Looks straight forward job.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a string, you should pass the type of the form you're looking for as a parameter.
Something like this should work (untested!).

```
public void FindOrCreateForm(Type formType)
{
bool opened = false;
foreach (Form forma in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (forma.GetType() == formType)
    {
        opened = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!opened)
{
    Form frm = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form already exist");
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this - as formType I send form name and I get error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Modules.frm_TestForm' to 'System.Type' and 'Modules.frm_TestForm' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: try passing Modules.frm_TestForm.GetType() or typeof(Modules.frm_TestForm) as argument

Comment: It works but one more problem - with mdi child - frm.MdiParent = this shows error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'Mod.GetForm' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Comment: you need to put in an explicit cast like this:
frm.MdiParent = (Form)this;